# Spark csv to dataframe skip first row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading csv to dataframe using -

```scala
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").
                option("delimiter", ",").load("file.csv")
```

but my input file contains date in the first row and header from  second row.
example

```
20160612
id,name,age
1,abc,12
2,bcd,33
```

How can i skip this first row while converting csv to dataframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are several options that I can think of since the data bricks module doesn't seem to provide a skip line option:

**Option one**: Add a "#" character in front of the first line, and the line will be automatically considered as comment and ignored by the data.bricks csv module;

**Option two**: Create your customized schema and specify the `mode` option as `DROPMALFORMED` which will drop the first line since it contains less token than expected in the customSchema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};

val customSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("id", IntegerType, true), 
                                    StructField("name", StringType, true),
                                    StructField("age", IntegerType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
                         option("header", "true").
                         option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").
                         schema(customSchema).load("test.txt")

df.show
```

> 16/06/12 21:24:05 WARN CsvRelation$: Number format exception. Dropping
>   malformed line: id,name,age

```
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1| abc| 12|
|  2| bcd| 33|
+---+----+---+
```

Note the warning message here which says dropped malformed line:

**Option three**: Write your own parser to drop the line that doesn't have length of three:

```
val file = sc.textFile("pathToYourCsvFile")

val df = file.map(line => line.split(",")).
              filter(lines => lines.length == 3 && lines(0)!= "id").
              map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2))).
              toDF("id", "name", "age")

df.show
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1| abc| 12|
|  2| bcd| 33|
+---+----+---+
```